# AWS Fargate failing healthchecks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a task definition that I want to launch using Fargate on AWS. Right now without any load balancing and stuff. I just want to run the task. The definition is following:

```json
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::941606308749:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/web",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 512,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME",
          "value": "blacksheep-dev2"
        },
        {
          "name": "CELERY_BROKER_HOST",
          "value": "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/941606308749/BlackSheepLearnsBroker"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
          "value": "postgres"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_HOST",
          "value": "blacksheeplearnsdb.c9a9ehc0s9ms.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
          "value": "postgres"
        },
        {
          "name": "ROLLBAR_ENABLED",
          "value": "True"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 1024,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "941606308749.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/blacksheeplearns:latest",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": {
        "retries": 3,
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -f http://localhost:8000/health/ || exit 1"
        ],
        "timeout": 5,
        "interval": 30,
        "startPeriod": 30
      },
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": {
        "project": "BlackSheepLearns"
      },
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "web"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::941606308749:role/ecsTaskRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:941606308749:task-definition/web:14",
  "family": "web",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 14,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

However, when I want to start it, it gets up for about 1,5 minute and then it gets killed. I suspect this has something to do with healthchecks.

At certain point it just receives a kill signal and stops. Here it is configured without a target group or load balancer:

```
2021-07-10 10:48:40
[2021-07-10 08:48:40 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:48:39
[2021-07-10 08:48:39 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:48:39
[2021-07-10 08:48:39 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:48:39
[2021-07-10 08:48:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:33
WARNING:rollbar:Rollbar already initialized. Ignoring re-init.
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:33
WARNING:rollbar:Rollbar already initialized. Ignoring re-init.
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: ROLLBAR_KEY
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: ROLLBAR_KEY
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: SECRET_KEY
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:32
INFO:root:Retrieving secret: SECRET_KEY
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:29
[2021-07-10 08:46:29 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:29
[2021-07-10 08:46:29 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:29
[2021-07-10 08:46:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:29
[2021-07-10 08:46:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
2021-07-10 10:46:29
[2021-07-10 08:46:29 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
ccb94e999e294bdbaadc3f941b786603
```

So from what I see, the service is getting up, the gunicorn (server for python web apps) is getting up, listening on port 8000, that I've mapped and so on. I also have exposed `/health/` endpoint in my application in order to allow easy and lightweight healthchecks (it only returns 200s). And yet in the service console I keep getting:

> 3a52c067-63bd-4d58-a092-a69d29380962
> 2021-07-10 11:46:08 +0200
> service web task 7982151a4a904a82b077fc48410dd672 failed container health checks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there is no ALB, then what would be checking your health status?

Comment: It seems that Fargate is responsible for this.

Comment: Are you running the task as part of an ecs service?

Comment: There is a health check in the task definition which if I understand correctly is only in play if it’s part of a service

Comment: Yes. Using Fargate.

Comment: Simply put, your health check is failing. Your service is listening on localhost 8080 so it points to a problem with the /health/ endpoint

Comment: Have you tried without any health check just to start the process of elimination?

Comment: @RonanCunningham well, yes, it ceased to fail tasks, but it's a bit strange question. I've attatched logs showing that the task is being stopped because of failing checks. It would be strange if after turning off the healthchecks it would keep appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do 2 checks related to healthcheck and write what you find?

- Does it pass healthcheck when you increase the timeout duration?
- What happens when you increase the cpu or ram on the task definition you provided?